# ORDER BY MySQL statement

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to order a list of options stored in a MySQL table. The issue is, the result are quite varied and there is a specific way I would like them displayed. I have been trying out the `SUBSTRING` and `SUBSTRING_INDEX` functions on the ORDER BY clause, however not getting the exact order that I am after..

The data I'm trying to sort (and the result I'm looking for):

```
1 Colour Print (white base)
2 Colour Print (white base)
3 Colour Print (white base)
4 Colour Print (white base)
1 Colour Print (coloured base)
2 Colour Print (coloured base)
3 Colour Print (coloured base)
4 Colour Print (coloured base)
Embroidered (white base up to 5000)
Embroidered (coloured base up to 5000)
```

However, the closest I can get to it is:

```
1 Colour Print (coloured base)
2 Colour Print (coloured base)
3 Colour Print (coloured base)
4 Colour Print (coloured base)        
1 Colour Print (white base)
2 Colour Print (white base)
3 Colour Print (white base)
4 Colour Print (white base)
Embroidered (coloured base up to 5000)
Embroidered (white base up to 5000)
```

The query I am using is:

```
select * from options ORDER BY SUBSTRING(optionName, 4);
```

I also tried with `SUBSTRING_INDEX` but that just got even more messier..

Is this possible or should I admit defeat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the `c` from coloured comes before `w` from white in the alphabet, this will not be possible.

Well, unless you want a really complicated solution:

```
 SELECT * FROM options ORDER BY
   SUBSTRING(optionName, 4, 1),
   SUBSTRING(optionName, 18, 1),
   SUBSTRING(optionName, 1, 1)
```

If you have the option to modify the table structure, I'd suggest to add a sortOrder column.

Comment: Hi Glorfindel, apologies, I pasted the wrong text (amended now). Thanks for the suggestion. At present its just a workaround until a new site is up and running (which will have an additional sorting column)